# How to run a python script on Azure for CSV file analysis

Tags: python, azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-cosmosdb

I have a python script on my local machine that reads a CSV file and outputs some metrics. The end goal is to create a web interface where the user uploads the CSV file and the metrics are displayed, while all being hosted on Azure.

1. I want to use a VM on Azure to run this python script.
2. The script takes the CSV file and outputs metrics which are stored in CosmosDB.
3. A web interface reads from this DB and displays graphs from the data generated by the script.

Can someone elaborate on the steps I need to follow to achieve this? Detailed steps are not essentially required, but a brief overview with links to relevant learning sources would be helpful.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use Azure VM?

Comment: @SadiqKhoja Seems like my supervisor (I'm an intern) is well versed with Azure and that is what he recommended.

Comment: I would deploy the python script on Azure Function and web application on App Service Plan, that would be cost effective and less hussle of managing VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an article that lists the primary options for hosting sites in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/quickstarts-app-hosting

As Sadiq mentioned, Functions is probably your best choice as it will probably be less expensive, less maintenance, and can handle both the script and the web interface. Here is a python tutorial for that method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01

Option 2 would be to run a traditional website on an App Service plan, with background tasks handled either by Functions or a Webjob- they both use the webjobs SDK, so the code is very similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-a-website-with-azure-app-service/

VMs are an option if either of those two don't work, but it comes with significantly more administration. This learning path has info on how to do this. The website is built on the MEAN stack, but is applicable to Python as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-a-website-with-azure-virtual-machines/